# How to create new group using SoCo (python)?

Tags: python, sonos

I would like to create a group and specify a coordinator for it based on a device name.

```
import soco


devices = soco.discover()

for device in devices:
    if device.player_name == 'Kitchen'
        # Define a new group with a coordinator here...
        # device.group...
        break
```

The reason for that is I'd like to programmatically play a specific song in the Kitchen (and only the Kitchen) but the device is already part of group and is not a coordinator. Thus I get the following error:

```
The method or property "play_uri" can only be called/used on the coordinator in a group
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks